# Modify all links' href attribute using plain javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I have an email template to send on a shipping notification that includes a shipping tracking number as below and I need to clear all the spaces from `href` using plain javascript:

```
<a class="press-bt" id="clearSpace" href="https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item?trackNumber=JX12 0008 990 90GB">TRACK</a>
```

I can get it right using jQuery but not using Javascript

I am trying to do it this way:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var str = document.getElementById("mylink");
    document.write( str.replaceAll("\\s+","") );
});
```

Working code using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').attr('href', function (_, val) {
        return val.replace(/\s/g, '');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you target `mylink` in the jQuery?

Comment: Jquery works! I need it on plain JS

Comment: Yes, but why do you not use `$('#myink').attr`?

Comment: @Andy I think he wanted to change all links but started with one link for a test. That's why plain JS only uses one element.

Comment: I don't think so, because it's only one email form with one anchor containing the tracking number. Eh. Doesn't matter. Between our two answers he's bound to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the element by its `id`, grab the href attribute, and set it again by removing the spaces.

```
var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
var href = link.getAttribute('href');
link.setAttribute('href', href.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should, if possible, remove the spaces server-side. I hope you understand **no** javascript will run in the emails you send.

```
// This prevents multiple `window.onload` conflict
window.addEventListener("load", clearLinks);
// This allows you to call the function even later if needed
function clearLinks() {
  // Get list of all links in the page
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
  // Loop through links
  for(var i=0,l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
     // No need to use `getAttribute`, href is defined getter in all browsers
     links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(/\s/g, "");
  }
}
```

In modern browsers, you can replace the for loop with `Array.prototype.forEach`. This method can be normally called on arrays (`[ ... ]`), but the list returned by `getElementsByTagName` is not an array, so use this trick:

```
function clearLinks() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
  // Loop through links
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link) {
    link.href = link.href.replace(/[cC]/g, "c");
  });
}
```

Search for `Function.prototype.call` to learn more about calling functions on objects.

Comment: Thanks for the post, unfortunately my Mac GPU stopped working when working on this piece of code :-( now I'll have to wait a week until I can get it fixed, I'll post the feedback whenever it's back..

Comment: @Skwashy well I hope you're not implying this code burnt your graphic card. That wouldn't even be funny.

Comment: Not because the code Lol I use my mac at top all time Cinema 4D, 3D Max, After Effects, Photoshop, etc...